# Exposing local api inside WSL to physical devices and emulators

Tags: windows, api, networking, local, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm working on a react native app from a windows 10 computer. I installed WSL, set up my backend needs on it, and I can see my api responding on localhost from windows, no problem on that end.

Now I would like to call it from my mobile app - both from an android emulator using Android Studio and from my physical android device (using Expo) connected to the same local network over wifi.

Using Ngrok it could work, exposing my localhost to a public url, but that's not what I'm looking for. I want it all to remain local if possible. My pc's local ipv4 is `10.0.0.8`, but nothing comes out on that address (not from the mobile app neither from my desktop browser, which works when using `localhost`).

My Ubuntu inside WSL says:

```
~$ cat /etc/hosts

# This file was automatically generated by WSL. To stop automatic generation of this file, add the following entry to /etc/wsl.conf:
# [network]
# generateHosts = false
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.1.1       JB-PC.localdomain       JB-PC

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

My `ipconfig`:

```
Carte Ethernet Ethernet :

   Suffixe DNS propre à la connexion. . . : Home
   Adresse IPv6 de liaison locale. . . . .: fe80::f04e:ae2b:40b9:3d82%6
   Adresse IPv4. . . . . . . . . . . . . .: 10.0.0.8
   Masque de sous-réseau. . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Passerelle par défaut. . . . . . . . . : 10.0.0.138

Carte Ethernet vEthernet (WSL) :

   Suffixe DNS propre à la connexion. . . :
   Adresse IPv6 de liaison locale. . . . .: fe80::68c3:25c9:588a:a957%17
   Adresse IPv4. . . . . . . . . . . . . .: 172.20.32.1
   Masque de sous-réseau. . . . . . . . . : 255.255.240.0
   Passerelle par défaut. . . . . . . . . :
```

localhost pings on ::1 :

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>ping localhost

Envoi d’une requête 'ping' sur JB-PC [::1] avec 32 octets de données :
Réponse de ::1 : temps<1ms
Réponse de ::1 : temps<1ms
Réponse de ::1 : temps<1ms
Réponse de ::1 : temps<1ms

Statistiques Ping pour ::1:
    Paquets : envoyés = 4, reçus = 4, perdus = 0 (perte 0%),
Durée approximative des boucles en millisecondes :
    Minimum = 0ms, Maximum = 0ms, Moyenne = 0ms
```

and 127.0.0.1 pings as well, and pinging localhost with `-4` option gives the same output:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>ping 127.0.0.1

Envoi d’une requête 'Ping'  127.0.0.1 avec 32 octets de données :
Réponse de 127.0.0.1 : octets=32 temps<1ms TTL=128
Réponse de 127.0.0.1 : octets=32 temps<1ms TTL=128
Réponse de 127.0.0.1 : octets=32 temps<1ms TTL=128
Réponse de 127.0.0.1 : octets=32 temps<1ms TTL=128

Statistiques Ping pour 127.0.0.1:
    Paquets : envoyés = 4, reçus = 4, perdus = 0 (perte 0%),
Durée approximative des boucles en millisecondes :
    Minimum = 0ms, Maximum = 0ms, Moyenne = 0ms
```

What should I do to make this work?

Comment: Networking works different on WSL1 and WSL2. If you use WSL2, the Linux will have a different IP address. -- Are you running Linux on WSL2?  What is the IP address in the linux system (e.g. by running `ip address`)? Can you ping to that IP address from the Windows?

Comment: Thanks, found a solution :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I found a solution thanks to https://superuser.com/a/1618446/757755 I successfully used option 2 and used port forwarding, with the script found [here](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4150#issuecomment-504209723). Remember that your PowerShell script has to be ran as administrator.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Here's the quick & dirty way: simply run `npx expose-wsl@latest` **before** starting the expo dev server.

Disclaimer: I'm the author of the package ;-)
See the [expose-wsl github repo](https://github.com/icflorescu/expose-wsl) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

Adding in my Solution since I always get back to this issue whenever a mobile app task is assigned to me:

Basically I had to use the script Jeremy used in the selected answer, run execution policy unrestricted, run the script as .\fwdwsl.ps1 and back to default.

Here is my script:

```
$remoteport = bash.exe -c "ifconfig eth0 | grep 'inet '"
$found = $remoteport -match '\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}';

if( $found ){
  $remoteport = $matches[0];
} else{
  echo "The Script Exited, the ip address of WSL 2 cannot be found";
  exit;
}

#[Ports]

#All the ports you want to forward separated by coma
$ports=@(80,443,10000,3000,5000,8000);


#[Static ip]
#You can change the addr to your ip config to listen to a specific address
$addr='127.0.0.1';
$ports_a = $ports -join ",";


#Remove Firewall Exception Rules
iex "Remove-NetFireWallRule -DisplayName 'WSL 2 Firewall Unlock' ";

#adding Exception Rules for inbound and outbound Rules
iex "New-NetFireWallRule -DisplayName 'WSL 2 Firewall Unlock' -Direction Outbound -LocalPort $ports_a -Action Allow -Protocol TCP";
iex "New-NetFireWallRule -DisplayName 'WSL 2 Firewall Unlock' -Direction Inbound -LocalPort $ports_a -Action Allow -Protocol TCP";

for( $i = 0; $i -lt $ports.length; $i++ ){
  $port = $ports[$i];
  iex "netsh interface portproxy delete v4tov4 listenport=$port listenaddress=$addr";
  iex "netsh interface portproxy add v4tov4 listenport=$port listenaddress=$addr connectport=$port connectaddress=$remoteport";
}
```